# automate page transition using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fadeout

I would like to add a Page Transition from my front page to my wordpress site , I have index.html which contains a picture , and I would like to redirect visitors after 5 seconds to my wordpress site located on mysite.com/wordpress , I have found this great Tutorial and it works  awesome ,[How to Use jQuery to Make Slick Page Transitions](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/) but my question is there a way to automate the transition without having to click on "link"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try doing like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").css("display", "none"); 
        window.location.replace("your_new_url");             
    },5000);    
});
```

Comment: @user3714364 you're welcome, btw you could mark it as Accepted Answer if it worked for you... :)